# Redundant If statement warning

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

```
if ( a > b) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

With the above code Netbeans gives `"Redundant if statement"` warning and suggest changing it to :

```
return a > b;
```

I think the first version is easier to read and prefer using it in my code. I want to know if there is any disadvantages of it compared to the suggested one.

Comment: I think is readability, I prefer the netbeans suggested code. You might want to compare the .class generated by both versions. I think they would be optimized to the same set of instructions.

Comment: I would find such a warning annoying.  In the above simplistic case maybe the second form would be better, but any more complex at all and the first could be argued to be more readable.

Comment: I prefer the latter version, but you should be able to set your preference. If Netbeans doesn't have an option for this you should make a feature request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
if ( a > b) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

consists in pushing the value of `a` on the stack, pushing the value of `b` on the stack, popping both and checking the result of `>`. If it's `true`, push the value of `true` on the stack, then pop it and return it. If it's `false`, branch to further down in the bytecode, push the value of `false` on the stack, pop it and return.

In the case of

```
return a > b;
```

you're pushing the value of `a` and `b` on the stack, then popping the values and pushing the result of `>` on those values onto the stack. Then popping that value and returning it.

So

```
return a > b;
```

is **unnoticeably** more efficient at the byte code level.

(IMO I find the second more readable and I believe most will, too.)

Comment: The efficiency here is irrelevant or, quite possibly, nonexistent once the JIT compiler gets finished with it. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time" -- Donald Knuth

Comment: Agree w/ @DavidConrad: Don't worry about javac or the JIT compilers job, and more important: don't teach new programmers to do that. If you code is to slow, take a high level overview first, then measure, then optimize.

Comment: @ErikI Would you like me to remove the information about how the byte code is generated by the compiler or would you like me to emphasize the _unnoticeably_? I've gone ahead and done that latter in anticipation.

Comment: Hi and thanks for caring! My point was that I'm fairly certain that Java will optimize this away completely. Modern compilers are amazing. That said, I'll remove my downvote and leave you with figuring it out for now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does include some additional computations from compiler point of view. Need to allocate memory for booleans(that u r returning) and do a >b computation. A>b returns Boolean so if u return that it is easy.
They both have same from logic though.

Comment: See David Conrads comment.